# Why did the author use present tense in the sentence?

Tags: usage, present-tense

The book, which is the source of this passage, was written in 2014. Why did the author use ***enters*** in the sentence?

> By the beginning of the 20th century psychology as science had
> barricaded itself against any liaison with culture. The focus on
> experimental psychology of lower psychological functions was expected
> to make psychology a real science. Linkages with history in general
> and cultural history in particular would have been obstacles on the
> royal road to scientific purity. The result was another century of no
> serious work on complex cultural phenomena by psychologists. Music — a
> favourite topic for early psychologists in the 19th and early 20th
> century — has not been a prominent research field as the discipline
> ***enters*** the 21st century. The story is similar in the case of religion, which in its various forms frames social and personal lives
> all over the world. It had mostly been abandoned by psychologists as a
> research field by the 1920s. Nearly a hundred years later, our lives
> are filled with ever re-emerging spiritual sentiments that are easily
> captured by new religious organizations.

[An Invitation to Cultural Psychology](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=ch2JCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=Nearly%20a%20hundred%20years%20later,%20our%20lives%20are%20filled%20with%20ever%20re-emerging%20spiritual%20sentiments%20that%20are%20easily%20captured%20by%20new%20religious%20*liaison%20!%22&source=bl&ots=wzUF9FwCe8&sig=ACfU3U1iPJz3PdfcT3yRmMYokj-CzJ7NIg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1raXox8DwAhUmbN4KHU3SCz0Q6AEwAnoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=Nearly%20a%20hundred%20years%20later,%20our%20lives%20are%20filled%20with%20ever%20re-emerging%20spiritual%20sentiments%20that%20are%20easily%20captured%20by%20new%20religious%20*liaison%20!%22&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

2014 is still close to the beginning of the 21st century (only 14% of the way through, in fact). So it makes sense for someone writing in 2014 to say that we are still entering the 21st century.

In addition, the author is saying that music was not *and continues to not be* a prominent research field. If the field of music research had taken off around, say, 2008, it would not make sense to use the present tense here—the author might instead write "Music **had not** been... as we **entered** the 21st century" (and then explain how and when that changed). But because the field did not grow like that, using the present continuous is logical.